# What is a suitable device for fast temperature process control?

Tags: temperature, pid-controller

Here is a ceramic heater catalog:
[product sheet](https://www.watlowdistributor.com/HTML/Watlow-Ultramic-brochure.pdf)

These heaters can ramp up as fast as 150 degrees C per second. I am not entirely sure what I am searching for but let's look at my use case:

Say I want a set point of 160 degrees C with acceptable variance of +/-5 degrees C as measured by the internal (to the heater) thermocouple. The thermal load in this case is one gram of aluminum in very good thermal contact and a large heatsink of PTFE with poor to no thermal contact.

Do solutions exist for this type of fast temperature control? If so I would prefer to go with that solution but if not, I am open to suggestions for damping the system for use with a normal on-off process controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a process controller with 10Hz or better sample rate and analog out should be fine with this. Don't try to use the el cheapo ones.

Comment: Is analog out analogous to continuous control of output voltage or maybe something like a triac dimmer?

Comment: Usually it will be a 0-5V, 0-10V or 4-20mA output that you then need to feed into an external power controller. The power controller can be a phase control type, which is like a dimmer, but usually will use SCRs. Modern controllers are self-tuning PID so they will slow the response down to match a 10Hz or better sample rate, but if you need fast response, better to go for 20 or even 40 samples/second (price will be higher usually).